# Group by count query takes a long time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table like this:

```
   Column    |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       
-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('oks_id_seq'::regclass)
 uname       | text                        | not null
 ess         | text                        | 
 quest       | text                        | 
 details     | text                        | 
 status      | character(1)                | not null default 'q'::bpchar
 last_parsed | timestamp without time zone | 
 qstatus     | character(1)                | not null default 'q'::bpchar
 media_wc    | integer                     | not null default 0
Indexes:
    "oks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "oks_uname_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (uname)
    "last_parsed_idx" btree (last_parsed)
    "qstatus_idx" btree (qstatus)
    "status_idx" btree (status)
```

And I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(status), status FROM oks GROUP BY status ORDER BY status;
```

Which results in:

```
  count  | status 
---------+--------
 1478472 | d
   23599 | p
   10178 | q
 6278206 | s
(4 rows)
```

Which is great, but this takes forever, and for some reason Postgres keeps the whole index on disk, because disk activity is really high during the query.

```
Sort  (cost=1117385.91..1117385.92 rows=4 width=2) (actual time=54122.991..54122.993 rows=4 loops=1)
   Sort Key: status
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1117385.82..1117385.86 rows=4 width=2) (actual time=54122.280..54122.283 rows=4 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on oks  (cost=0.00..1078433.55 rows=7790455 width=2) (actual time=0.009..47978.616 rows=7790455 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 54123.487 ms
(6 rows)
```

In my config I have the memory usage set at 
work_mem = 128MB

Any ideas about how I can optimize such queries that use group by on the whole table?  This seems unrealistically slow as it would have been much faster with flat files storage.

Edit:
I was able to get the query to run in a fraction of a second by modifying the postgres config files.  Specifically, setting

```
fsync = off
synchronous_commit = off
full_page_writes = off
commit_delay = 2000
effective_cache_size = 4GB
work_mem = 512MB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
```

Not sure if these are optimal, but these options work in my case.
fsync = off helped the most I think.

Comment: In theory Postgres should be able to use an index scan on `status_idx` which should be faster than the seq scan on the table. Does this change if you run a `vacuum analyze` on the table?

Comment: seems to run much faster. Dropped to 9 seconds.  Now analyze shows  GroupAggregate as the only thing called with Index Only Scan using status_idx on oks.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it went back to its old ways after 50 minutes. Now total runtime is 128 seconds.  Explain Analyze is the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

try to use cstore. It is column store "table".

info:
https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw

how to use cstore:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970937/psql-using-cstore-table-for-aggregation-big-data